# jquery - on play not working when using $(document).on('play', 'video', function(){})

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, video, playback

I don't know why on play doesn't work!!!

```
$('video').on('play', function(){ alert('working'); });

$(document).on('play', 'video', function(){ //not working });
```

As I know for audio/video we should use get(0) to get the dom but for the second one it hasn't got that, what's your guess/suggestion?

**Another approach problem**

so it seems nobody knows this so i decided to use click event. In click event I check whether it is paused or not, if it's paused so pause others and play this else pause this one either.

```
$(document).on('click', 'video', function(){
    if($(this).get(0).paused)
    {
        $(this).get(0).play();
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).get(0).pause();
    }
});
```

it works in firefox but the problem starts when using chrome or ie. When clicking on video it works but when clicking on play button it doesn't detect click event has triggered!!! how can I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with javascript solution below:

```
document.getElementById('vid1').addEventListener('play', function(){ alert('working'); });
```

Note: "vid1" is the Id of the video element.

Comment: Thank you @Ronnee007 but have you tested it youself? it didn't work :(

Comment: Yes I tested it and it worked fine for me. Another solution that you can try for is adding "onplay" attribute in the video tag in HTML itself. Let me know if this works!

Comment: I don't know how I can present my happiness, but THANK YOU! I **** myself to fix it, and your last suggestion worked like a charm!! Thanks bro :)

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('play', function (e) {
    var video = e.target;
    if (video.nodeName === 'VIDEO') {
        console.log('onplay', video);
        // do something ...
    }
}, true);
```